# How to remove the badge in app shortcut icon?

Tags: android, android-shortcut, pinned-shortcut

[image]How to remove the badge in app shortcut icon in android? When i create app shortcut programmatically, along with the icon specified for shortcut, app icon comes at the bottom-right corner of the icon. I don't want that badge.

Here is the code I used

```
    public static void addShortcutToHomeScreen(Context context)
{
    if (ShortcutManagerCompat.isRequestPinShortcutSupported(context))
    {
        ShortcutInfoCompat shortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(context, "#1")
                .setIntent(new Intent(context, Splash.class).setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) // !!! intent's action must be set on oreo
                .setShortLabel("Test")
                .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.logo))
                .build();
        ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(context, shortcutInfo, null);
    }
    else
    {
        // Shortcut is not supported by your launcher
    }
}
```

Comment: what technology or platform you use for sending push notification?

Comment: I am not using push notification. I was trying to add a shortcut for my app, the issue is in oreo only.

Comment: Put some image of your issue

Comment: Add your shortcuts code here. so we get some idea.

Comment: Can you share the code that ended in this result?

Comment: Please read this doc. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges#java

Comment: Have u able to check this 
Android 8.0’s Pinned Shortcuts https://www.androidauthority.com/android-nougat-oreo-static-dynamic-pinned-shortcuts-845686/

Comment: My question is not about notification badge. It is app shortcut. @MartinZeitler

Comment: @MartinZeitler i have added the code. My question has no similarity to what you suggested. At least read my question once,

Comment: I haven't mentioned anywhere that it is a notification badge.

Comment: this might not even be possible... with only a screenshot, this can easily be misleading (there's lots of deleted answers taking it for a notification badge)... [this](https://medium.com/@calren24/android-app-shortcuts-new-and-improved-50139d4688f6) shows it... it's a feature, to see what application it even is

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thank you. But whatsapp and clean master apps creates shortcuts automatically. How?

Comment: @Athira it's probably not a shortcut icon, but a common app launcher icon.

Comment: @Athira Did you find the solution? I have spent many hours researching but can not find an answer. Some app still can make this but I can not @@

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way. These additional options are added by launcher, not your app itself. Obviously, uninstall options will be not there if your app is not possible to be uninstalled (it's system app for example).

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I found two ways we can create a shortcut programmatically of any app without badge

1. By using Widget
   We can achieve this by dynamically creating widgets. If anyone wants the code for this, I can provide it as well.
2. Create an Activity with transparent launcher icon
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZVAX.png

use this setActivity method for set our transparent launcher icon activity to shortcut

**shortcutInfo.setActivity(ComponentName(mActivity!!, OpenAppActivity::class.java))**

**Complete method of 2nd option**

```
fun addShortcut(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
    val launchIntent =
        mActivity!!.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(MApplication.packageNameApp.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
            ?: mActivity!!.packageName)
    val shortcutInfo = ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(
        mActivity!!.applicationContext,
        mainViewModel.selectedApp!!.appName
    )
        .setIntent(launchIntent!!)
        .setShortLabel("test")
        .setAlwaysBadged()
        .setActivity(ComponentName(mActivity!!, OpenAppActivity::class.java))
        .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithBitmap(bitmap!!)).build()
    val broadcastIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT)
    mActivity?.registerReceiver(
        object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(
                c: Context?, intent: Intent
            ) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    mActivity!!.applicationContext,
                    "Icon Created",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                mActivity!!.unregisterReceiver(this)
            }
        }, IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT
        ), Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
    )
    val successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        mActivity!!,
        99,
        broadcastIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(
        requireContext(),
        shortcutInfo,
        successCallback.intentSender
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no such option for [ShortcutInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutInfo) nor [ShortcutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager). it depends on launcher and it should show this badge that user will know in which app it will open. without this icon there is no option to recognize which app added it (besides opening), thats not so user friendly... for example you could impersonate another app by adding e.g. FB icon and "Facebook" shortcut name, and `Activity` opened by this shortcut may be faked log-in screen. in short: this icon is/should be there for security reasons

in my launcher long press starts moving shortcut immediately (no dropdown menu as for launcher icon) and I don't have "App info" option on top of screen (in "moving mode"), only "Remove"

maybe consider adding an [AppWidget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) stylized as launcher icon with app name? shortcuts are available since API25, widges are there from start, and since API26 you can [requestPinAppWidget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#requestPinAppWidget(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) (similar dialog style as for adding shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a shortcut (NOT app widget) **via the Widgets screen** (something like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcjvAcQ9Ytc&t=21s&ab_channel=AlexTern)) could be a workaround. Create an activity that filter `<action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />`, and create the shortcut in that activity by manually creating an `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT` intent (instead of via `shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent()`) and returning it with `setResult()`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71206869/5785726) for details. Please note that the actual behavior may still be different when using a different launcher (it may not work under some launcher). I only tested with Pixel Launcher and Microsoft Launcher under Android 11 and Android 12.

Answer (score -1):

First download an icon pack from PlayStore (loads to choose from). 
Go back to the screen with the offending icon.
Press and hold icon you want to change (i.e. the one with the extra Chrome logo) and press edit.
Press change icon.
It will give you option to choose from the icon pack so press that.
You will then have a large choice of icons so choose the one which best represents the current icon or choose something wildly different.
Then tap OK.
It will change the icon and have no extra badge.

Comment: The OP was obviously asking how to change this from within his app, not as an user...

Answer (score -2):

Try this may be work for you. `mChannel.setShowBadge(false);`

```
String id = "my_channel_01";
CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
mChannel.setDescription(description);
mChannel.setShowBadge(false);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
```

Comment: another solution follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061462/disabling-oreo-notification-dot

Comment: This is notification badge, can't you see the image in my question?

Comment: your question is "How to remove the badge in-app shortcut icon?". I can see the question. however, you are not placing your code over here how can we give the right answer. don't be over smart.

Comment: Read question description also

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score -2):

Add below line in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Code for creating a shortcut on Desktop,

```
 private void addShortcut() {
        //Adding shortcut for MainActivity
        //on Home screen
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BottomNavigationActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "My Shortcut");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.alert_clock));
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);


    }
```

Comment: This does not work since OREO. INSTALL_SHORTCUT does not work. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#as

Answer (score -2):

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
         channel.setShowBadge(false)

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to remove badge lower than oreo?