# Disabling Oreo Notification dot

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, badge

On Oreo (API 18), I don't want to use notification dot.
But it show notification dot default.
For instance, YouTube push notification but don't use notification dot.

I'am using NotificationChannel
And I tried using

```
NotificationChannel.setShowBadge(false)
```

But it didn't work.
How can I do this?

---

youtube - has no notification dot

[image]

myApp - has notification dot

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When you create your notification under Oreo you must create a channel instance and assign it to the notification.  You use `setShowBadge` on your instance.

Below is my code which correctly removes the badge.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel";
CharSequence name = context.getString(R.string.channel_name);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    channel.setShowBadge(false);

    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context, CHANNEL_ID).setSmallIcon(iconID)
        .setContentTitle(task.taskTitle)
        .setContentText(task.taskNote).setOngoing(true).setWhen(0)
        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSound(null)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

notificationManager.notify(task.driveId, NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```