# Remove badge from custom android icon

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-shortcut

I am creating an application for creating icons, like [Ume Icon Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ume.shortcut) and now I am using this code to create an icon

```
    public static void createShortCut3(Context context, Drawable drawable, String shortcutname, String packagename){
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packagename);
    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        ShortcutManager shortcutManager =
                context.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);

        if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
            ShortcutInfo pinShortcutInfo =
                    new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "app-shortcut")
                            .setIntent(intent)
                            .setShortLabel(shortcutname)
                            .setIcon(Icon.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(bd.getBitmap()))
                            .build();

            Intent pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent =
                    null;
            pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent = shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(pinShortcutInfo);

            PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo,
                    successCallback.getIntentSender());

        }
    }
}
```

But all my icons are created with this badge.

[image]

As I understand it, you can't just remove it. But in ume icon changer and in other applications this is done somehow [through the widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcjvAcQ9Ytc&t=21s&ab_channel=AlexTern).

How can I implement a similar function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the badge in app shortcut icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71207316/5785726)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create shortcuts without that app icon badge by creating shortcuts through the widget via the deprecated `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT` intent type. Create an activity that filter `<action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />`, and create the shortcut in that activity by manually creating an `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT` intent (instead of via `shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent()`) and returning it with `setResult()`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71206869/5785726) for details. Please note that the actual behavior may still be different when using a different launcher (it may not work under some launcher). I only tested with Pixel Launcher and Microsoft Launcher under Android 11 and Android 12.