# Remove the app icon from the pinned shortcut android

Tags: java, android, shortcut, android-shortcut

After 8 android, my application icon appears on the shortcuts.

[image]

I know that this was added specially to informing the user which app has created the shortcut.

Here is the code that is currently being used to create the icon.

```
   ShortcutManager shortcutManager = (ShortcutManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SHORTCUT_SERVICE);
    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) ic;
    if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
        Intent shortcutInfoIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        shortcutInfoIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        shortcutInfoIntent.putExtra("pckg", pck);

        ShortcutInfo info = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "iconId")
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bd.getBitmap()))
                .setShortLabel(label)
                .setIntent(shortcutInfoIntent)
                .build();

        PendingIntent shortcutCallbackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(info, shortcutCallbackIntent.getIntentSender());
    }
```

I know that this is a fairly popular problem, but no one has provided a normal solution.
But I need to take it away somehow

I'm sure that this is possible because it is implemented in [x icon changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.hexman.xiconchanger), where icons are created without these badges.

Please write all your ideas how to fix it

Comment: Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sure that this is possible because it is implemented in x icon changer, where icons are created without these badges.

They use app widgets for that. See the "ABOUT THE WATERMARK" in [the Play Store listing that you linked to](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.hexman.xiconchanger).

> Please write all your ideas how to fix it

Write an app widget.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was already possible to remove the badge through the widget, I would like to find a way to remove it without the widget

Comment: Also in x icon changer, it is no longer necessary to create a widget, the icon is already created without a badge, you can try it yourself

Comment: Hi @Michael2322, you say it was already possible to remove the badge through the widget, could you specify more detail about how to remove the badge by creating shortcuts via widget? Only adding new activity that filters `CREATE_SHORTCUT` intent and creates a shortcut in that activity seems doesn't work, not sure if other operation is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently using the recommended `shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent()` will cause displaying app icon at the corner of the shortcut it created, but the deprecated `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT` way still works and there won't be an app icon in the created shortcut if you use this way and create your shortcut via the Widgets screen!

So the first step is to make your shortcut show on the Widgets screen. To make do this, ensure `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>` is in your AndroidManifest.xml file, and create an activity that filter `<action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>`. The manifest file will look like this.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>

    <application
        ...>

        ...
        <activity
            android:name=".shortcuts.YourShortcut"
            android:label="@string/shortcut_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:exported="true"
            ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    ...
```

In your activity, you'll need to create a shortcut. Normally we use `setResult()` with `RESULT_OK` as result code and the `shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent()` to create the intent for the 2nd argument, which will cause the app icon displayed in the corner of the shortcut. To avoid the shortcut icon, we can create the intent manually with the deprecated `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT` type. Something like:

```
    fun onOpen() {
        // things to do when user click the shortcut...
    }

    private fun setupShortcut() {
        val intent = Intent().putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, Intent(this, this::class.java)) // we use this::class.java here, then clicking the shortcut will trigger onOpened()
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, shortLabel)
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, iconResource));

        setResult(
            RESULT_OK,
            intent
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT) {
            setupShortcut()
        } else {
            onOpened()
        }
        finish()
    }
```

Once we did these, you can see the shortcut appears on the Widgets screen. When the user drags the icon to the launcher, there will also not show the application icon in the corner.

Please note that the actual behavior may still be different when using a different launcher (it may not work under some launcher). The above code is tested with Pixel Launcher and Microsoft Launcher under Android 11 and Android 12.

Comment: Hello, could you give a more detail code? I do not understand the flow of code (when an Intent with action Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT is sent to MainActivity)

Comment: When a user tries to drag any icon from the Widgets screen to launcher, onCreate() will be called with action set to ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT. If that's the case then we'll use the setupShortcut() to create a shortcut.